# Type hint for list with fixed start and end types but variable length

Tags: python, types

I'm wondering if there is a way to type hint when I expect a list that I **know** will end with `bool` and start with a variable number of `int`s?

What I'm effectively trying to do is

```py
def f(xs: List[int, ..., bool]):
    pass
```

where `...` is some variable number of `int`s (zero or more).

Comment: No. `list` objects require *homogenous types*. While Python allows you to put whatever you want, you shouldn't be doing this to begin with

Comment: Note, you should be using a `tuple` here, probably, but `tuple` the spec does not support what you want to express for a `tuple` type either

Comment: Yes, I appreciate this isn't an ideal design choice, but it is a list I'm being given by an external library and I'm trying to write a function to convert it into something "better". Yes, I also tried with a tuple, but as you say it isn't supported.

Comment: Yes, well, the best you can do is `list[int | bool]`, or `list[Union[int, bool]]`

Answer (score 1):

I side with @dangom on this one. You could restructure how you are passing the arguments to your function, or use `Union` instead.

```
from typing import List, Sequence, Union


def more_correct(ints: Sequence[int], flag: bool) -> List[int]:
    ...

def less_correct(xs: Sequence[Union[int, bool]]) -> List[int]:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of ints is variable up to a certain limit, you can use the union of distinct Tuples as a workaround, as in:

```py
from typing import Tuple, Union

TupleBoolLast = Union[
 Tuple[int, bool],
 Tuple[int, int, bool],
 Tuple[int, int, int, bool],
 Tuple[int, int, int, int, bool],
 Tuple[int, int, int, int, int, bool],
]

def f(xs: TupleBoolLast):
    pass
```

Alternatively you could have a type that shows that your lists are a combination of ints and bools, though that does not enforce order:

```
ListIntBool = list[Union[int, bool]]

def f(xs: ListIntBool):
    pass
```